# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [1,85,85,9] vs. [1,85,85] [Op:GreaterEqual]

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have a 4 dimensional x matrix. I want to compare the median element of the elements in the x matrix with the elements in the row of the matrix. but i am getting error

```
x >= x[:,:,:,4]
```

when i run the above process
`tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [1,85,85,9] vs. [1,85,85] [Op:GreaterEqual]`
i am getting the error.

example

```
print(x[:,0:1.0:1,])
```

`[21.398438 20.5625 20.433594 20.03125 25.220703 25.798828 19.097656 17.792969 21.001953]]]`

I want to compare the median element "25.220703" from the sample data above with all the data in this row. and finally
`[[[[False False False False True True False False False]]]]`

i need to get it. But I am getting the above error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of taking the 5th element, take a slice with just that element. Then the number of dimensions doesn't change: the shape of `x[:, :, :, 4:5]` will be in your case `(1, 85, 85, 1)`, and it can be broadcasted into `(1, 85, 85, 9)`.

```
x >= x[:, :, :, 4:5]
```

For example:

```
x = tf.constant(np.random.randint(0, 9, (1, 2, 2, 9)))
```

Output:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 2, 2, 9), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([[[[5, 0, 8, 2, 6, 0, 6, 2, 2],
         [1, 4, 3, 5, 4, 0, 3, 1, 3]],

        [[0, 3, 5, 5, 0, 1, 2, 8, 5],
         [8, 5, 0, 1, 8, 7, 7, 8, 1]]]])>
```

Then:

```
x >= x[:, :, :, 4:5]
```

Output:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 2, 2, 9), dtype=bool, numpy=
array([[[[False, False,  True, False,  True, False,  True, False,
          False],
         [False,  True, False,  True,  True, False, False, False,
          False]],

        [[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
           True],
         [ True, False, False, False,  True, False, False,  True,
          False]]]])>
```

The difference between `x[:, :, :, 4]` and `x[:, :, :, 4:5]` is just the shape:

```
x[:, :, :, 4]
```

Output:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 2, 2), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([[[6, 4],
        [0, 8]]])>
```

Compare with slice:

```
x[:, :, :, 4:5]
```

Output:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 2, 2, 1), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([[[[6],
         [4]],

        [[0],
         [8]]]])>
```

Comment: What should I do as a result?
Should I use x[:, :, :, 4] instead of x[:, :, :, 4:5]?

Comment: Use `x >= x[:, :, :, 4:5]`

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you are comparing the whole Matrix with another Matrix here,

```
x >= x[:,:,:,4]
```

Tensorflow cannot broadcast a matrix with different shapes to compare therefore you are getting this error. The shape of x is (1 , 85 , 85 , 9) but when you are accessing the elements of x in the form of x[:,:,:,4] so what you are doing is basically slicing the last dimension into a single dimension. Now, the shape of x would be (1 , 85 , 85), so you can't compare the two matrices with different shapes.

Now your problem is to compare the median element of a row with all of its elements then first access the median element and then compare it whether it's greater or not, I will show you in this code.

```
x[:,0:1,0:1,][0][0][0][median_index] > x[:,0:1,0:1,]
```

Now, this would return what you want, but in othercase you can't compare two matrices of different shapes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
but that's not exactly what I want.
namely
In my 4-dimensional matrix, there are 9 values in the last channel. I want to take the median (5th) element from these 9 values and compare it with the remaining 8 values. I'll do 1 if it's large, 0 if it's not. I hope I was able to explain.

In your method, only the values in the first row and column are processed.

Comment: Try this: [1 if x[0,0,0,median] > x[0,0,0,i] else 0 for i in range(9) if i!= median]

Comment: I wrote the first row and column as an example. here batch, row columns i can't enter 0.